# Using Hyperledger Composer on Oracle Autonomous Blockchain Service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm trying to explore Oracle cloud's autonomous blockchain service to deploy a Hyperledger composer business network. 
Oracle's Blockchain service uses Hyperledger Fabric as the backbone but I faced issues deploying the network to it.

Has anyone used Hyperledger Composer with Oracle's blockchain service. Does it support composer networks?

Comment: Hi Naudy, welcome to stackoverflow. could you be more specific on what issue you have faced when setting up the Hyperlledger Fabric? Have you contacted Oracle's support? Just a suggestion, server-related questions better asked on [ServerFaults](https://serverfault.com/) unless it involves some programming.

Comment: Hi Bagus, I am not facing any issues with Hyperledger Fabric. Oracle's cloud provides blockchain as a PaaS. This is Hypledger Fabric running as a service on Oracle's cloud. I want to check if we can install Hyperledger Composer networks on this service. Which we can do in general on other platforms. I also did connect with Oracle support but the response was not much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the answer is yes. Since they are based on the same fabric, as long as the versions are compatible, you can use the composer with OBCS.

[check this out](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/blockchain/faq/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. Have you tried it? I did try it a few times and ended up with some server errors. I was not even able to go through the installation step. I'll give it another try. But it you have any steps to follow please let me know.

Comment: Hey Naudy, sorry for the late response. I have used it before and I do remember it being a pain in the rear. If you're still having trouble could you show me the error so that I could troubleshoot it in more detail for you.